# Positioning SE bars with different aesthetics in geom_errorbar using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I have to give SE values manually in a grouped bar plot in R. However, SE lines don't take the same positions with bars. I understand the x variables that I defined `(x = Species)` in each `geom_errorbar` are causing this but I have to define it since I'm using multiple datasets.

So here's my data:

```
Datatemp = data.frame( Species = c("Oak", "Oak", "Pine", "Pine","Oak", "Oak", "Pine", "Pine"),
                       Status = rep(c("Above", "Below"),4),
                       Sex = c(rep("Male",4), rep("Female",4)),
                       Value = c(6.86, 7.65, 30.13, 35.71, 7.13, 10.33, 29.24, 31.09),
                       SE = c(0.7354684, 1.9648560,3.6734597, 4.5276121, 
                              0.7881132, 1.9564864, 3.4784320, 4.243139))
```

Here's the code for the barplot:

```
DatatempA = Datatemp %>% filter(Species == "Oak")
DatatempB = Datatemp %>% filter(Species == "Pine")

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = DatatempB, 
           mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Value, fill = Status), 
           stat='identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width=.67) +
  geom_errorbar(data = DatatempB,aes(x = Species, ymin = Value-SE, ymax = Value+SE), 
                position = position_dodge(.9), width = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Status trees", 
                    labels = c("Above","Below"),
                    values = c("#7393B3","#0F52BA"),
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill=c("gray75", "gray25")))) +
  new_scale_fill() + 
  geom_bar(data = DatatempA, 
           mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Value, fill = Status), 
           stat='identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width=.67, show.legend=FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(data = DatatempA, aes(x = Species, ymin = Value-SE, ymax = Value+SE), 
                position = position_dodge(.9), width = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Status trees", 
                    labels = c("Above","Below"),
                    values = c("#EADDCA","#F4BB44")) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name= "Sex of trees")) +
  xlab("Species") + 
  ylab("Value") +
  theme_light() + theme(axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(0, "pt"))
```

And here's the output:
[image]

As you can see, the error bars were grouped in the middle and It would be great if you could suggest a way to position them in the respective bars. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the approach by @TarJae I think that the `ggnewscale` package is not really needed to achieve your desired result and you can simplify by using just one dataset and mapping the interaction of `Species` and `Status` on `fill`. To still achieve your desired result you can drop the fill legend and use a fake legend for `Status` for which I map `Status` on the `color` aes. Afterwards I set the colors to `"transparent"` and override the `fill` color for the legend as you did using `override.aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Datatemp, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(
      y = Value,
      fill = interaction(Status, Species),
      color = Status
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.73), width = .67
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(
    aes(ymin = Value - SE, ymax = Value + SE, group = Status),
    position = position_dodge(.73), width = 0.2
  ) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#EADDCA", "#F4BB44", "#7393B3", "#0F52BA"),
    guide = "none"
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = rep("transparent", 2),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = c("gray75", "gray25")))
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "Sex of trees")) +
  xlab("Species") +
  ylab("Value") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(
    axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(0, "pt")
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's good to know that something like `fill = interaction(Status, Species)` could simply do the trick.

Comment: If we change the order of geom_col and geom_errorbar, we will see a modified plot displaying only the upper part of the error bar. In my opinion, this resembles the 'original' so-called dynamite plot. @Stefan, I am curious about your opinion on which presentation is better or more appropriate.

Comment: @TarJae Personally, I would show the whole error bar to make clear that the range of uncertainty extends to both sides of the estimate.

Answer (score 2):

I would use this strategy:

1. Define the fill aesthetics,
2. Create a interaction term `SpeciesStatus`,
3. group and fill with `SpeciesStatus`,
4. do your grouped bars with errorbar as usual.

```
colors <- c("Oak_Above" = "#F4BB44", "Oak_Below" = "#EADDCA",
            "Pine_Above" = "#0F52BA", "Pine_Below" = "#7393B3")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

Datatemp %>% 
  mutate(SpeciesStatus = interaction(Species, Status, sep = "_")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Value, fill = SpeciesStatus, group = SpeciesStatus)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Value - SE, ymax = Value + SE), 
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  facet_grid(Sex ~ .) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name= "Sex of trees")) +
  xlab("Species") + 
  ylab("Value") +
  theme_light() + theme(axis.text.y.right = element_blank(),
                        axis.ticks.y.right = element_blank(),
                        axis.ticks.length.y.right = unit(0, "pt"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although it's annoying to see that the way I chose wasn't feasible when it comes to these kinds of plots. However, there is one tricky part of this solution that doesn't fit the output that I wanted: the legend. It should strictly only show the status information as black and white shaded as it's given above. `scale_fill_manual(name = "Status trees", labels = c("Above","Below"), values = c("#7393B3","#0F52BA"))`. Is there a way to do it? Because now scale fill is using `colors`.